# Restrict which rows can be edited by users in a relational database

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express

I've got a Postgresql database set up with user, business, campaign and voucher tables

Each voucher has a parent Campaign, each campaign has a parent business and each user can belong to one or more businesses linked via a business_user FK table.

How do I stop a user changing rows that don't belong to a business he belongs to? 
I use jwts for managing sessions and they store the userId.

Do I use inner joins? But then how can I deal with the many to many business and user relationship?

Comment: Just do this in the application layer. Test conditions before you execute any queries. Use [Seqelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/) to make models that have this logic built-in.

Comment: Using knex so would I just run a bunch of queries in the application layer on the db to see if they're linked?

Comment: Well "a bunch of queries" but usually with more rhyme and reason. Any ORM will help you organize this.

Answer (score 0):

To  even show the technique I need to refer to columns so I make the following assumptions:

- Each table has a column ID, and this column is defined as the PK.
- Each table has the appropriate foreign key column(s) and names as
  *RefTable*_id
- Each table has a non key column COL.

The technique then is to a (and exists select...) where the select follows FK chain to business from the table being updated and from business_user to business. So updating voucher becomes:

```
update voucher vch 
   set col = '...'
 where vch.id = &vid
   and exists
       ( select null 
           from campaign camp 
           join business bus  on bus.id = camp.business_id
           join business_user bu on bu.business_id = bus.id
          where camp.id = vch.campaign_id
            and bu.user_id = &uid
       );
```

where &vid and &uid are for vouhcer.id and user.id respectively.